# Strange line on apache2 error log

Tags: linux, security, vps

When I view my apache error log, it seems to be producing quite strange output

```
[Sun Oct 27 08:32:51.340219 2019] [:error] [pid 23596] [client 
23.224.45.82:49441] script '/var/www/xiong.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 27 08:32:51.476946 2019] [:error] [pid 23596] [client 23.224.45.82:49441] script '/var/www/jing.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 27 08:32:51.579280 2019] [:error] [pid 23596] [client 23.224.45.82:49441] script '/var/www/ganshiqiang.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 27 08:32:51.681687 2019] [:error] [pid 23596] [client 23.224.45.82:49441] script '/var/www/n23.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Oct 27 08:32:51.786535 2019] [:error] [pid 23596] [client 23.224.45.82:49441] script '/var/www/infos.php' not found or unable to stat
```

<sub>There's 100+ more identical line</sub>

I don't have the file `n23.php` nor `infos.php` on my `/var/www` dir, what could it be? Is it possible that my VPS has been compromised ? If so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't have the file `n23.php` nor `infos.php` on my `/var/www dir`, what could it be?

These are likely automated web attacks. These are often random in the sense that there are tools that will try a list of these attacks against any web server they come across in the hope that the web server will be vulnerable (i.e. it's unpatched or has been previously compromised unbeknownst to the person who runs the server).

> Is it possible that my VPS has been compromised?

In theory, but since these attacks failed (`script not found or unable to stat`), it seems less likely. These types of attacks  in and of themselves do not indicate a compromised host. Everyone who runs a public web server gets these types of entries in their logs at some point (and you will likely continue to get such entries as long as you run one).

> If so, how would I go about [fixing] this?

Without knowing anything about your VPS, as an offhand suggestion, restoring from a snapshot that you believed was uncompromised would probably be the simplest route. That, or just rebuilding the server from scratch. But these solutions seem like overkill unless you've noticed any other odd behaviors. As mentioned, a few log entries like the ones you have presented here are (relatively speaking) not abnormal. The volume *could* be worrying (100+ lines), but since you are renting from a VPS provider (which undoubtedly hosts many websites), it doesn't seem that odd that an attacker might put more effort into compromising one or more of them.

One thing to consider is manually filtering these types of bad requests. With Apache, this often essentially entails writing blacklists in conjunction with some combination of [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) (`<RedirectMatch>`) and `<FilesMatch>` to discard these types of requests individually as they are received.